# Wide or narrow side between blade and fence in rip cut on table saw

Tags: table-saw, safety, rip-cut

I've heard lots of rip cut guides say that you should have your workpiece between the blade and the fence and the offcut on the free side of the blade.

The thing that bothers me about this advice is surely it should be based on which side is wider / narrower.

For example let's say I have a long board that is 200mm wide and I want to rip it into 4 strips of 50mm width, ignore the Kerf for this example. For the first cut should the there be ~150mm of wood between the blade and the fence or should there be ~50mm?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what makes you think the thicker piece belongs between the blade and the fence?

Comment: 95%+ keeper piece is against the fence, with offcut on the left side. I think this implies that moving the fence for each cut is correct procedure for many users, sawing a second time for final width.

Comment: Forgot to mention I was coming at this question as a novice user concerned about safe cutting

Comment: Since you are a novice I want to mention there are a few things you should bring yourself up to speed on, including *all* the basics of saw operation and adjustment. I presume from your use of metric that you're in Europe? If so you won't have to contend with a long rip fence so that's one worry avoided. Now look at why you might want dedicated rip and crosscut blades rather than just a GP blade. Research feather boards and similar, and use them as much as you can. Make yourself a range of push sticks/blocks and use them or a commercial option *all the time*; every cut, without exception.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, you'd set your fence to 50mm (~2" for those who like Freedom Units ;) and run it through that way. If you should happen to mis-set the fence a bit and you get it at 49.9mm or 50.1mm, at least your strips are all the same. If you put the "off cut" portion between the blade & fence, you have to adjust the fence for every single cut. I've *never* seen anyone do this. <sup>See addendum at the end for an update on this</sup>

While 50mm isn't much room to get your hand safely past the blade without risking losing a finger, this is what a push stick/block is for.

One thing you *do* want to consider is *NOT* having the fence on the same side as your blade tips to if you're making an angled cut. In this lovely ASCII art, you'll see that the cut piece between the fence and blade can get pinched, and that's where you get kickback:

```
  +--+         <--- Fence
  |  |   v--------- Work piece: this part could get pinched and cause kick back
  |  |
  |  |------\----
  |  |-------\---  <--- Tilted blade
---------------------   Saw table
```

Instead, you'd want to put the fence on the other side to significantly reduce the chance of kick back:

```
              +--+
              |  |
              |  |
  ---\--------|  |
  ----\-------|  |
---------------------------
```

In this scenario, the off cut piece won't get pinched between the tilted blade and the fence - it's free to move if it needs to. The "keeper" piece would be free to rise up some if necessary.

---

---

I will note that since I originally wrote this answer, I have learned about a tool/jig called a "thin rip guide" or "narrow rip guide". This is a device that clamps into one track in your table saw and has a wheel against which you position the stock. You put the jig to the left of the blade and the fence to the right. You adjust the jig so the gap between the wheel & blade is the size of piece you need to keep, then make a cut. You then reposition the *fence* by placing the board against the jig's wheel and move the fence until it hits the wood.

This effectively puts the "keeper" piece to the left of the blade and the "off cut" between the blade and fence.

The goal of this is to be able to safely make thin cuts without risk of the thin piece falling between the blade & insert (hint: a zero-clearance insert also helps), and without it getting stuck between the blade & fence where it's difficult to push past the blade, even with a push stick, and could possibly kick back at you. It even allows you to reinstall the blade guard with its built in anti-kickback pawls for even greater cut safety.

With this setup, you *do* move the fence with every cut, but you've got the jig to make the movement quick and easy and the measurement is repeatable, instead of having to do the math on each one, relying on the fence's scale and your ability to work in imperial fractions (or the easier metric) and having to also calculate in the blade kerf for each cut.

One example of the "thin rip jig" is [this one from Woodpeckers](https://www.woodpeck.com/thin-rip-guide.html). From what I understand, they make very high quality (and expensive) tools and a lot of people recommend them. I cannot recommend them personally because I don't own any. The Woodpeckers was simply the first one I found in my searching - they're also made by a variety of other manufacturers at differing price & quality levels.

Comment: Ok so from a safety perspective there isn't much difference but it's much more efficient if you are doing multiple cuts to have the workpiece be between the fence and blade ?

Comment: If by "work piece" you're referring to the piece you're after (the 50mm one in your example), then yes. To me, the "work piece" is the piece of wood being cut. From the "work piece", I get the "final piece" (or "keeper") and the "off cut". It's just a terminology thing, I don't think there's anything "official", and I may be the only one who thinks of it that way, but I want to be clear what _I_ mean so as to not confuse others.

Comment: Good answer. To address the safety question in the comment above, it’s safer to always do an operation the most familiar way. So no goofing around flipping the fence to the other side because that changes how your body is positioned and how your hands are working.

Comment: @LukeDeFeo, *"Ok so from a safety perspective there isn't much difference"* Actually there is. Narrower pieces (even not *narrow* narrow as when cutting thin strips) are more likely to deflect, and when this occurs between blade and fence it increases the chance of kickback. I can't find a reference online, but IIRC old-school table saw practice exclusively called for the narrower piece to be left of the blade.

Comment: "to the left side of the blade", @Graphus? But which side of the blade is the fence on when the narrow piece is on the left? Isn't it really more of an issue of "between the blade & fence" or "not between the blade & fence"? Maybe older table saws could only have the fence on 1 side, but everything I've seen in the last 30 years could have it on either side.

Comment: Isn't it still normal, almost universal, for the fence to be right of the blade as looking from the rear of the saw? (Presumably because most users are right handed.)

Comment: @graphus what do you consider to be narrow?

Comment: @LukeDeFeo, it's sort of irrelevant what I'd consider to be narrow (since it's a given how subjective this determination would be) but a few articles and guides on table saw use suggest that approximately 30-35mm might be the lower limit. Somewhat related, you might want to look at some thin-strip ripping guides. As you might expect, if you're cutting many thin strips of equal width (although here width becomes thickness) it's common for the strip to be *right* of the blade, i.e. between blade & fence, so one setup continues to cut equal strips regardless of the width of the workpiece.

Comment: @FreeMan Please correct: 50 mm is about 2", not 4". Otherwise great answer.

Comment: Excellent point, @Andrey. 25.4mm = 1". I knew that, but apparently I couldn't maths on the day I wrote this.

Comment: @Andrey, \*doh* how could I have missed that at the time?

Comment: You and me both, @Graphus, you and me both...

Comment: Well you have an excuse, you think (I presume) exclusively in Freedom Units so you have to do the math. I should be able to look at Imperial measurements in certain ranges and immediately see an exact or close metric equivalent without having to formally convert. 50mm would certainly be one! I mean I'm not converting 1/64" on autopilot but 3/4", 1/2", 1/4", 1/8" & 1/16", we have to do that all the time. I know some woodworkers who can do it with 5/8", 3/8" as well, and know all the metric equivalents of nominal wood sizes too, but I can't keep them all straight in my head.

Comment: I do use Freedom Units, but the math with metric is _so_ much easier... I'm constantly trying to convert °C to °F when watching F1 & Supercars, just to try to get the right ranges in my head. I know what 72°F feels like, but I'm not sure what 22°F feels like w/o a little help from the interwebz. (Oh, they're the same!) I can reasonably estimate 3", but 75cm? nope.

Comment: I do note that @Graphus mentioned the "thin rip guide" back when I originally wrote this 2+ years ago, but that really didn't catch my attention. I've since seen several videos & reviews of them and that's what got the jig stuck in my head and prompted today's update.

Answer (score 0):

> I've heard lots of rip cut guides say that you should have your workpiece between the blade and the fence and the offcut on the free side of the blade.

It's not really a hard and fast rule, and there are several factors to consider: safety, accuracy, feasibility, efficiency... Normally, you want the workpiece between the blade and fence because you set that distance directly with the rip fence scale; there's no need to measure the stock and then subtract the fence setting and the blade kerf. Also, unless you've already trimmed the far edge of the stock (by running it through the saw with most of it between blade and rip fence) you can't count on the edges being parallel.

> The thing that bothers me about this advice is surely it should be based on which side is wider / narrower.

I'd only consider that insomuch as it impacts one of the factors (above) that I care about. Most saws have a rip capacity of at least 30"; any cut that you can make safely within your saw's range should be OK.

> For example let's say I have a long board that is 200mm wide and I want to rip it into 4 strips of 50mm width, ignore the Kerf for this example. For the first cut should the there be ~150mm of wood between the blade and the fence or should there be ~50mm?

I'd set the fence to 50mm and make the cuts. That guarantees that they'll all be the same width, which is often important, and it saves the trouble of moving the fence after every cut. It's no less safe than starting with the fence at 150mm because the fence is going to be set at 50mm for the last cut, so I need to make sure I can do that safely anyway -- use a push stick/block.

Answer (score 0):

when I was at Building College my tutor said if possible 99% of the time your work piece you are keeping should be between the blade and rip fence, the waste should be on the free side. This as you say is normally with the wider piece between blade and fence. Generally when pushing the piece through the saw, subject to right hand only, your thumb and fingers are placed closest to the fence with your little finger running along the top of the fence as a guide and support. When the piece your keeping is less than 100mm 4inch, I suggest only using push sticks, remember to stand to one side (generally left) to avoid kick back if not using feather boards.